# sql to linq, same query but not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

i have this in my SQL server management studio

```
      SELECT DISTINCT Hours.id, Hours.hour, Shift.Date, Shift.Doctor
      FROM dbo.Hours, dbo.Shift
      WHERE(Shift.Date= '2017/08/04' AND Shift.Doctor= 530) AND (Hours.Id 
      NOT IN(SELECT Shift.Hour                                                                                            
      FROM dbo.Shift) )
```

This brings me exactly what i want.

but when im trying in LINQ :

date is 2017/08/04
and id is 530

```
 var hoursFree = (from s in db.Shift
                  from h in db.Hours
                  where ((s.Date == date && s.Doctor == id) && !(from s in db.Shift select t.Hours).Contains(h.Id))                                                                                 
                  select h).ToList().Distinct();
```

shouldn't LINQ brings me exactly the same thing ?

Comment: it depends on what `date` and `id` are. Additionally, that `not in` clause is not the same.

Comment: Not sure about this, but you have `from s in db.Shift` twice in the `LINQ`. Will the `!(from s in db.Shift ` be the filtered data?

Comment: Are those the only columns?  Id, Hour, Date and Doctor?  If not, then you would be calling distinct on other fields as well.

Comment: Please describe what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Showing the results from both data sets would help.

Comment: Your SQL is calling distinct across four columns from two tables whereas your LINQ is calling distinct on all columns of one table.

Comment: @WEI_DBA you were right, i removed "from s in db.Shift " and changed a few things and its working perfectly! i love you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var hoursFree= (from h in db.Hours
                where !(from s in db.Shift
                where (s.Date == date && s.Doctor == id)
                select s.Hour).Contains(h.Id)                                                                              
                select h).Distinct().ToList();
```

this is now working, Thank you WEI_DBA

Comment: Do the `.Distinct()` before the `.ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your original query.

1) you are not selecting out the same values. In the SQL query you are selecting four fields: Hours.id, Hours.hour, Shift.Date, Shift.Doctor, but in the LINQ query you are selecting only the fields from the Hours table, and all of them.  Instead you should select same data using:  new { h.Id, h.Hours, s.Date, s.Doctor}

2) The use of Distinct() after ToList() causes the Distinct() method to run on the data locally after the data is returned to the client, which can have a different behavior than DISTINCT running on the server.  You should instead order them the other way, .Distinct().ToList().